# $\int \frac{\sin x}{1+2\sin x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, closed-form

calculate:
$$\int \frac{\sin x}{1+2\sin x}dx$$
I tried using $\sin x=\dfrac{2u}{u^2+1}$, $u=\tan \dfrac{x}2$ and after Simplification:
$$\int \frac{2u}{u^2+4u+1}×\frac{2}{u^2+1}du$$
and I am not able to calulate that.

Comment: There's an algorithm for integrating rational factions. See e.g. https://www.math24.net/integration-rational-functions/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before doing that substitution I might say

$\int \frac{\sin x}{1+2\sin x} \ dx\\
\int \frac 12 \frac{2\sin x + 1 - 1}{1+2\sin x} \ dx\\
\int \frac 12 -  \frac{1}{1+2\sin x} \ dx\\
\int \frac 12 \ dx  -  \frac 12 \int \frac{1}{1+2\sin x} \ dx$

Now when we do the substitution it isn't as messy.

$\frac x2  -   \int \frac{1}{u^2 + 4u + 1} \ du$

Answer (score 2):

Since $u=\tan\frac{x}{2}$ gives$$\int\frac{dx}{1+2\sin x}=\int\frac{2 du}{(u+2)^2-3}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{3}}\operatorname{artanh}\frac{u+2}{\sqrt{3}}+C=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{3}+2+\tan\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{3}-2-\tan\frac{x}{2}}+C,$$we have$$\int\frac{\sin xdx}{1+2\sin x}=\frac12x+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\ln\frac{\sqrt{3}+2+\tan\frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{3}-2-\tan\frac{x}{2}}+C.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use the partial fractions method (I think that is the name of it):

$$\frac{2u}{u^2+4u+1}×\frac{2}{u^2+1} =\frac{au+b}{u^2+4u+1}+\frac{cu+d}{u^2+1} $$

where you have to find $a,b,c,d$.

---

How do we do that? First get rid of the fractions:

$$4u = (au+b)(u^2+1)+(cu+d)(u^2+4u+1)$$

and now get rid of the brackets and then compare the coefficents...

Comment: $u^2+4u+1$ is sepratable so it can not be "$au+b$" on numerator

Comment: Why not?............

Comment: m and n are roots of $u^2+4u+1=0$ so partial fractions should be : $\frac{a}{u-m} + \frac{b}{u-n}$

Comment: yes, you can continue like that

Comment: but roots of $u^2+4u+1=0$ are not Integer so I think its going to be a little complicated

Comment: have you calculated my $a,b$?

Comment: not yet I will do it. I think it is very long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100168/discussion-between-hgs-and-aqua).

Answer (score 1):

Simplify first before substituting,

$$\int \frac{\sin x}{1+2\sin x}dx
=\frac12\int dx -\frac12 \int \frac{1}{1+2\sin x}dx$$
$$=\frac12 x -\frac12 \int  \frac{1+\tan^2\frac x2}{\tan^2\frac x2 +4\tan\frac x2 +1}dx$$
$$=\frac12 x -\int \frac{d(\tan \frac x2)}{\left(\tan^2\frac x2 +2\right)^2 -3}$$
$$=\frac12 x +\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\tanh^{-1}\left( \frac{
\tan\frac x2 +2}{\sqrt3}\right)+C$$